# During converting python code to C#, hmacsha encoding became a problem

Tags: c#, python

I'm familiar with python and very new to C#.

I'm trying to convert a python code to C# code, which is not going well

Here is part of my python code:

```
def make_signature(uri, access_key):
    secret_key = "****"     # secret key (from portal or sub account)
    secret_key = bytes(secret_key, 'UTF-8')
    method = "POST"
    message = method + " " + uri + "\n" + timestamp + "\n" + access_key
    message = bytes(message, 'UTF-8')
    signingKey = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

and I tried to convert it by this C# code:

```
            using (HMACSHA256 sha = new HMACSHA256(hmac_key))
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageRaw);
                string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64);

                // encode
                var hash = sha.ComputeHash(message);

                // base64 convert
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
```

I found out that these two code make different outputs despite of their same inputs.

Could anyone let me know how to convert it correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to Convert Base64 to string and vice-versa? I see your python code for it. If you want, I'll post an answer for converting to & back from Base64, in C# :)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do that. Actually, the python code is already proven working well, so it is the ground truth.

Comment: So, you want me to show you how to do it in C#? I'll post an answer now

Comment: Yep @Momoro Thank a lot in advance

Comment: No problem! I had fun helping :)

Comment: I think the conversion _itself_ is not your problem. You are just doing it one time too often.

Comment: @Fildor Could you explain more please?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in python, you hash your input and base64 it. In C#, you base64 your input, then hash _that result_ and then base64 again. See where I am going?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks to your advice, I could manage to pass authorization!! :D Thanks a lot! But now I fronted another problem...;(

Comment: What's your problem, Jinhoon? I may be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To convert to Base64, you can use this:

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
```

And to convert back!

```
    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
```

I am using `RichTextBox` for this example:

`richTextBox1.Text = Base64Encode(richTextBox1.Text);`, Convert TO Base64

`richTextBox1.Text = Base64Decode(richTextBox1.Text);`, Convert FROM Base64

You can change the `ASCII` `Encoding` to `UTF-8`, or any `Encoding` that **Visual Studio** offers :)

You don't *necessarily* **HAVE** to use a `public static string`, you can just take the code out and put it into buttons or `MenuStrip` `Items`

Now, prior to your question, here:

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

        var 1base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

        var 2base64 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(1base64);

        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(2base64); //This is the double encryption :)
    }
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I will try this and report it later :)

Comment: It's no problem! :)

Comment: How'd it work out, @Jinhoon Jeong? If it went well, you may mark this question as answered :)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort @Momoro , but It seemed my problem was not how to convert Base64, but converting Base64 twice(should be once) as mentioned.

Comment: "Converting Base64 Twice"? What does "Twice" mean? You want to convert a string to Base64, then convert the Base64 TO Base64 AGAIN? Or am I missing something? :D

Comment: Actually, I have C# code for that. I updated my answer for you (If that's what you wanted!)

Comment: My problem was, in python, I hashed my input and base64 it. In C#, I base64 my input, then hash that result and then base64 again....

Comment: "hash"? What is "hash" supposed to be, Jinhoon? :D Also, is the problem solved, or do you need more info? :)